# I need a 3 table join

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

This is my parent table acc_detial -

ACC_DETIAL example -

| acc_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Now i have 3 tables:

- ORDER
- EMAIL
- REPORT

Each table contains 100 rows and acc_id are ForeignKey from ACC_DETIAL.

In ORDER table I have a columns ACC_ID and QUANTITY. I want the count of ACC_ID and sum of QUANTITY.

ORDER table example:

| acc_id | quantity | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2022/01/22 |
| 2 | 5 | 2022/01/23 |
| 1 | 10 | 2022/01/25 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022/01/25 |

In EMAIL table I have a column name ACC_ID and I want count of ACC_ID.

EMAIL table example:

| acc_id | mail | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2022/01/22 |
| 2 | 10 | 2022/01/22 |
| 1 | 7 | 2022/01/23 |
| 1 | 7 | 2022/01/24 |
| 2 | 10 | 2022/01/25 |

In REPORT table I have a columns ACC_ID and TYPE and I want the count of ACC_ID and TYPE. Note that TYPE column has only two, possible values:

- postive
- negative

I want count of each, i.e. count of postive and count of negative in TYPE column.

REPORT table example:

| acc_id | type | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | positive | 2022/01/22 |
| 2 | negative | 2022/01/22 |
| 1 | negative | 2022/01/23 |
| 2 | postitive | 2022/01/26 |
| 2 | postitive | 2022/01/27 |

**I need to take this in a single i need answer as raw query or sqlalchemy.** Is it possible or not? Do I need to write separate query to get each table result ?

Result -

result based on above examplec -

| acc_id | total_Order_acc_id | total_Order_quantity | total_Email_acc_id | total_Report_acc_id | total_postitive_report | total_negative_report |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 12 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | Null | Null | Null | Null |

Comment: Is there any parent table of the tables mentioned? acc_id is the foreign key in the mentioned tables? If there is a parent table then, I can give a raw query to fetch what you want in one query.

Comment: @MuhammadDanishKhan acc_detial_table is the parent table where it have acc_id as primary key as you mentioned order, email, report table acc_id is foreign key

Comment: Please update your question with the result you want to achieve based on the sample data provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to aggregate then join as the following:

```
SELECT ADL.acc_id,
       ORD.ord_cnt AS total_Order_acc_id,
       ORD.tot_quantity AS total_Order_quantity,
       EML.eml_cnt AS total_Email_acc_id,
       RPT.rpt_cnt AS total_Report_acc_id,
       RPT.pcnt AS total_postitive_report,
       RPT.ncnt AS total_negative_report
FROM ACC_DETIAL ADL LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT acc_id, 
         SUM(quantity) AS tot_quantity, 
         COUNT(*) AS ord_cnt 
  FROM ORDERS
  GROUP BY acc_id
) ORD
ON ADL.acc_id = ORD.acc_id
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT acc_id, COUNT(*) AS eml_cnt
  FROM EMAIL
  GROUP BY acc_id
) EML
ON ADL.acc_id = EML.acc_id
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT acc_id, 
         COUNT(*) AS rpt_cnt, 
         COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE type='positive') AS pcnt,
         COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE type='negative') AS ncnt
  FROM REPORT 
  GROUP BY acc_id
) RPT
ON ADL.acc_id = RPT.acc_id
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/nXtPasMy)

Answer (score 2):

Sample :

```
Select
  `order`.`acc_id`,
  report_email_select.`type`,
  report_email_select.report_count,
  report_email_select.email_count,
  SUM(`quantity`) as quantity_sum
FROM
  `order`
  Left JOIN(
    Select
      report_select.`acc_id`,
      report_select.`type`,
      report_select.report_count,
      COUNT(*) as email_count
    from
      (
        SELECT
          report.`acc_id`,
          report.`type`,
          COUNT(*) as report_count
        FROM
          `report`
        WHERE
          1
        GROUP BY
          report.`acc_id`,
          report.`type`
      ) AS report_select
      INNER JOIN email ON email.acc_id = report_select.acc_id
    GROUP BY
      report_select.`acc_id`,
      report_select.`type`
  ) AS report_email_select ON `order`.acc_id = report_email_select.acc_id
GROUP BY
  `order`.`acc_id`,
  report_email_select.`type`;
```